# Have any "cures" been invented since the 1950's or so?

Tags: medical-science, history, medications, drug-development

A well reputed professor of neurology once mentioned to me that no drugs have been invented to cure human afflictions since the 1950's or 60's. Are there any drugs that have been invented since that time that are permanent cures of human ailments?

This is somewhat related to:

- [Is drug development far cheaper than Big Pharma wants us to believe?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3130)

Comment: Does this question also include surgical procedures?

Comment: I think the claim is that all the new molecules found after the fifties are nothing more than better versions of the same concepts.

Comment: That professor should have his medical license revoked. >:-(

Comment: Does __Viagra__ count? ... I mean for [jetlag](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/6676585.stm)

Comment: @Oliver_C: I think not, as it treats the symptom, but needs to be taken regularly, rather than curing the condition permanently after which treatment can stop.

Comment: Possibly off-topic: You can't really expect to accurately predict technological advancement by linear extrapolation anyway (even Moore's Law isn't _really_ a law). Tech in any field goes through breakthoughs, then lulls, it doesn't steadily increase at a constant rate.

Comment: Do vaccines count?  If so, there's Human Papilloma Virus (2000s), Chicken Pox (1995), Measels (1963), and Polio (1961/1955), just to name a few.

Comment: @ESultanik: HPV and Chicken Pox are good counter-examples. Measels and Polio fall into the 1950's-60's.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by cure. Antibiotics can cure many things, they first came out more or less in the 40's/50s but have been getting a lot better since then. In terms of other things a lot of it is not a cure in the classical sense so much as ongoing treatment. We can not cure Type I diabetes, but we can treat it to the point that the person lives a more or less normal life. In terms of cancer my father knows a guy who does childhood oncology, when he first became a doctor in the 1960's mortality from childhood cancer was 100%, today its less then 10%!

Comment: @Brian Oops!  Somehow I missed the "1960s" part (I must jave just been looking at the title of the question, which only contains "1950s").

Comment: @ESultanik: WebMD says there is no cure for HPV, but that it clears on its own: http://www.webmd.com/sexual-conditions/hpv-genital-warts/hpv-treatment-is-there-hpv-cure ; same for Chickenpox: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chickenpox ; do you have references for the cures?

Comment: @Brian: Well they're vaccines, so in a sense they're preemptive cures.  If one already has the disease then the vaccines won't help.  That's why I wasn't sure if they can be considered "cures".

Comment: @ESultanik: I'd say vaccines definitely ought to count as cures, too. So there are vaccines for HPV and Chicken Pox? Do you have links to them?

Comment: @Brian-- there's actually a huge controversy over the HPV vaccine, because abstinence groups claim it will lead to increased promiscuity.  Here's a link to the vaccine: http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm5920a4.htm and here's one to the controversy: http://pediatrics.about.com/od/immunizations/a/0307_hpv_cntvsy.htm  Here's one for Chicken Pox (which is administered to kids as a matter of course these days): http://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/vpd-vac/varicella/default.htm

Comment: @mmr: Thanks -- when was the Varicella vaccine invented? It looks like it was approved in 1995, but I don't see when it was invented

Comment: @Brian-- Takahashi et al in 1974.  http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=BFQq2-fIAJ8C&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=varicella+vaccine+invented+Takahashi+et+al.&ots=jfbSuxlH29&sig=GNozqw-j2v4oJFFIRucTMaMgQII#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: The cures listed here have various side effects and wouldn't be considered returning one fully to health. There are huge risks associated with anti venoms as well, and we only have them for some, not all venomous animals. While anti venoms save some patients, others die...that's not a cure. I agree that some treatment options have improved, but again, what's been cured? We all know antibiotics must constantly be improved upon, again not consistently effective. Stents improve a given situation but do not restore the human body to original condition and health, they get old and constantly need t

Comment: Voted to close as there is no notable claim here. Can you cite a published statement?

Comment: Thanks for this question. It's been a real eye opener. Exactly the kind of question that this skeptical group was meant for. You've alighted on something wonderful.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That is an incorrect statement, if we're stricts.

- **Bone marrow transplant** to cure children lymphoma is a good example of a cure developed after the 50's: http://www.fhcrc.org/science/clinical/ltfu/faqs/transplantation.html . The major breakthrough was to obtain successful allogeneic grafts, which was not possible before late 60's-early 70's. There's a classic review in the New England Journal of Medicine of 1975 talking about these advances: http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM197504172921605 (part 1) and http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM197504242921706 (part 2). Also, you might want to look at Donall Thomas' 1990 Nobel Laureate lecture: http://nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/medicine/laureates/1990/thomas-lecture.pdf
- **Stent grafts** to restore blood flow and prevent (diminish the chance of) restenosis. See http://www.fauchard.org/history/articles/jdh/v49n2_July01/charles_stent_49_2.html for the origin of the word stent and its many applications, and http://web.mit.edu/invent/iow/palmaz.html for endovascular stents in particular.

If you look for drug examples,

- **Imatinib** (Gleevec) fits the description. For treating leukemia. http://www.time.com/time/covers/0,16641,20010528,00.html
- **Abciximab** (Reopro) saved a huge number of lives after heart attacks. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10155090
- **Statins** to reduce the cholesterol level (even with its abuse and lack of concurrent diets). http://www.nature.com/nrd/journal/v2/n7/fig_tab/nrd1112_I1.html
- Combination drugs like the **HAART** therapy against AIDS is another. You could argue that it does not "cure" AIDS, but the vast increase in life expectancy with it makes it worth being in the list. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1716971/

That said, it is true that the *pace* in which cures have been achieved diminished considerably. We could hypothesise for a long time about *why* this is happening, including (but clearly not limited to) stricter regulations and higher costs, for example.

Comment: I suspect there's the low-hanging fruit principle.  We got cures for the easier-to-cure stuff first.

Comment: @David absolutely, that's one of the probable reasons also.

Comment: @Aleadam: Unless I've misread them, the reference indicates that bone marrow transplants started in the 1960's between twins; similarly stents have been around since at least World War II according to the reference.

Comment: @Brian about the transplant, I can say that pioneering of a technique is not the same as using it to cure diseases. Regarding to the stents, its use after angioplasty started in the 90's. There are stents for many procedures, but vascular stents (the ones used for treating clogged arteries) are a relatively new invention. It seriously revolutionized vascular surgery.

Comment: @Aleadam: Do you have references that indicate that? I don't seem to see those conclusions stated in the references given. Maybe I'm blind. ;)

Comment: @Brian http://web.mit.edu/invent/iow/palmaz.html

Comment: @ Aleadam: Thanks; added to wiki above. Is there a reference dating bone marrow transplant?

Comment: @Brian I added a more descriptive comment to the bone marrow transplant (including sources) and links with sources for all the drugs also.

Comment: There is some evidence to suggest that the use of imatinib and other tyrosine kinase inhibitors has in some cases lead to 2+ years where no cells bearing the BCR-ABL mutation were detected in the patient. However, it's very limited due to the small number of such "cures" and also that the detection methods are not sensitive enough to determine that the mutated cells are completely eliminated.  [Relevant](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/731307).  I believe cancer is considered cured with 5+ years of no relapse.  I should note though that I agree in principle.

Comment: I think OP is looking for examples of drugs that completely eliminate a disease after a course of treatment.  Statins are a bad example in this case; as I understand it, Statins are one of the poster children of the "Expensive drugs that alleviate symptoms but you have to keep taking for the rest of your life" which drug companies are far more likely to fund through trials than a one pill wonder cure.

Comment: Sofosvubir has a pretty high cure rate for HepC, that was previously uncurable.

Comment: Statins are not cures.

Comment: @LorenPechtel statins cure high cholesterol levels, they do not cure the cause of those high cholesterol levels. Yeah, I know it's nitpicking. But we're doing that here anyway.

Comment: @jwenting No, statins do not cure high cholesterol.  They simply control it.  That's the point of the issue--cures vs maintenance drugs that simply keep a problem at bay.  The latter means **far** more doses sold and thus is more attractive to the drug companies.

Comment: @LorenPechtel they remove the cholesterol, thereby curing the symptoms without curing the underlying cause. Hence the comment about nitpicking :) And some things simply can't be cured, only controlled, without replacing entire organs. And I'd not want a liver transplant for everyone who needs statins or metformin.

Comment: @jwenting Cure:  Take it for a period, then quit.  The problem is solved.  (Example:  Antibiotics.)  Control:  The problem is only solved while you take it.  (Example:  Statins.)

Comment: @jwenting - The claim above was made by a doctor so I'm fairly certain that the person who claimed that there have been no new cures are aware of drugs that treat cholesterol. In general, people who practice medicine have been complaining that we have not developed new cures, only treatments, because curing is not profitable while treatments force patients to spend money for life.

Answer (score 14):

Let’s have a look at the [list of drugs approved in the USA in 2011 alone](http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/InformationOnDrugs/ApprovedDrugs/ucm254242.htm) – particularly at the active ingredients, since presumably this is what the professor meant because it’s what “makes the cure tick”.

- [Ioflupane](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/summary/summary.cgi?cid=3086674), not a cure in the strict sense (a carrier for a radioactive iodine isotope) entered into the database in 2005.
- [Spinosyn D](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/summary/summary.cgi?cid=183094), first described in 1998 according to PubMed.
- [Vilazodone hydrochloride](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/summary/summary.cgi?cid=6918313&loc=ec_rcs), entered into the database in 2006.
- [Roflumilast](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/summary/summary.cgi?cid=449193&loc=ec_rcs), first published in 2001 according to PubMed.
- …

the list goes on. The claim is so trivially wrong and, quite frankly, ridiculous that I can’t help wondering in what context it was used.

Comment: Could you also explain what ailments these active ingredients *permanently* cure?

Comment: The cited drugs and their links don't indicate that these chemicals cure anything, or at least anything that hadn't already been cured (probably by something cheaper, pardon my cynicism).

Comment: @Lagerbaer “Permanently” is a pretty restrictive definition of cure. But Spinosyn D permanently cures a lice infection.

Comment: @Brian Spinosyn D cures lice infection. “or at least anything that hadn't already been cured” – again, this is a pretty restrictive, and not very useful, definition. If a new cure works better, or works for different people, it’s a valid investment. Your cynicism is misplaced without evidence.

Comment: @Konrad: It's a good point; however, spiralling health care costs can be in large part attributed to the rising cost of pharmaceuticals that provide at best the same cure as existing pharmaceuticals but at greater cost and often higher risk of complications. Unfortunately none of the drugs you've mentioned have been assessed for viability and cost effectiveness by any of the impartial agencies I know if (e.g. CADTH at http://www.cadth.ca/), though Roflumilast is being evaluated.

Comment: @Konrad: I also disagree that the definition is not very useful. It's valuable to know whether our legal and economic incentives advance cures for diseases that are as of yet uncured (e.g. MS, ALS, HIV, etc), as opposed to merely incentivizing the creation of (often more expensive) alternatives to existing cures.

Comment: @Konrad: If there's a reference that shows that Spinosyn D effectively cures lice infection better than the existing alternatives, it's certainly a candidate example.

Comment: @Lagerbaer -- Can you provide an instance of any ailments and active ingredients that provided *permanent* cures before the 1950s?  "Permanent" and "cure" just aren't things that go together much.  You can become reinfected with most things, in addition to the fact that as you get older, things just start failing to work, so prior "fixes" fail...

Comment: My comment was not meant to criticize the answer. I'd just have liked the list to not only name the cure but also what it cures so I don't have to follow each of the links individually.

Comment: @Brian Exploding drug design cost is a slightly different question though. Granted, it’s a very interesting topic. But the drugs whose development costs so much money nowadays are exclusively [“blockbuster drugs”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmaceutical_drug#Blockbuster_drug) and they are either completely new cures (no alternative) or are vastly superior to existing treatments (either in tolerance or efficiency) and therefore worth the money. Nothing else would sell sufficiently to break even.

Answer (score 9):

[Here's one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imipenem) pretty much picked at random. There have been quite a few antibiotics - entirely new classes - developed since the 1960s. These antibiotics cure disease.

Other chemotherapeutic agents (antibiotics are a type of chemotherapy) have also been developed since the 60s and these agents cure cancer.

So the answer is a resounding, 'Yes'.

Comment: Thanks; Does Imipenem cure anything that was not cured before? (e.g. MRSA?)

Comment: @Brian: A MRSA infection is quite curable. You wouldn't choose Imipenem though as it's a β-Lactam (same Phylum, if you will, as penicillins and cephalosporins). MRSA is resistant to β-Lactam antibiotics. I'd be very hesitant to say that Imipenem cures bacterial infections that have not been cured before. It's role is to work where penicillins or cephalosporins formerly did, but now don't due to growing resistance.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt One shouldn't look at antibiotics as a redundant development because previously developed antibiotics tend to stop being effective over time. Thus, although a new antibiotics may cure things that previously had a cure but it may also cure things that previously had a cure but currently does not have a cure or will not have a cure in the future

Answer (score 8):

I've started a community wiki to consolidate the answers.

The professor I spoke with mentioned one drug that was discovered, alas serendipitously, by [Barnett Rosenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnett_Rosenberg) that effectively cures (with over 85% success) testicular and ovarian cancer: Cisplatin. This is an ideal counter-example to the skepticism (though at it's heart the skepticism is about the ability of our economic and legal incentives to procure cures, pardon the pun).

Are there any other drugs that effectively cure anything that had not already been cured? Ideal answer would be listed as:

- date, **Cure**, ailments cured (references)

Drugs that do not qualify as cures include those that are not cures (i.e. address symptoms), those that are ineffective (i.e. never go "flat" on the [cure rate model](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047141137X) of e.g. Berkson and Gage, etc). I would consider vaccines to be cures because they effectively cure the spread of disease, and further they're cost effective prevention.

There are two issues that present challenges when answering this question:

1. Drugs that improve on existing cures; and
2. Advancements in treatment of symptoms.

#### Improving cures

A drug improves a cure if the number of people surviving increases significantly. When asserting that this invention is an improvement, a reference ought to give the measure of improvement.

#### Advances in treatments

While there have been significant advances in treatment of symptoms (AIDS, type-I diabetes, etc), proper cures of the same would respectively be: an anti-viral that eliminates HIV; a drug that eliminates the need for treatment of diabetes. I also acknowledge that some treatments have advanced, such as childhood cancers, while there are questions of long-term survival rates and recurrence, the real issue is whether the ailment can be permanently resolved.

---

### Cures discovered since 1969:

- 1978, [**Cisplatin**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisplatin), testicular and ovarian cancer ([Barnett Rosenberg/Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnett_Rosenberg))
- 1987, [**"Triple therapy"**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicobacter_pylori_eradication_protocols), cures [Helicobacter pylori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicobacter_pylori) infection ([World Journal of Gastroenterology](http://www.wjgnet.com/1007-9327/12/4888.asp))
- 1988, [**Intravascular Stent**](http://web.mit.edu/invent/iow/palmaz.html), cures post-angioplasty closing of arteries
- 1993, [**HPV Vaccine**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HPV_vaccine), cures HPV-6, 11, 16 & 18 ([Oxford Journals](http://jnci.oxfordjournals.org/content/98/7/433.full))

Comment: I do not think creating a wiki for this is a good idea. It will be severely incomplete at least. If you are serious about compiling info, I suggest you to read the Annual Reviews in Medicine, write to the medical societies and start a series of interviews with specialist physicians so they can tell you the advances in each field. The info you may get here will not be enough for any compilation.

Comment: @Aleadam: It's a fair point to be sure, and I'll think about how to address it with a comment in the wiki, but the point of the Wiki would be to compile a list of some compelling examples to refute the skepticism. It needn't be exhaustive, only persuasive.

Answer (score 5):

[Omeprazole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omeprazole#History) was released in the 1980s. Other 'meprazoles' have appeared later. They are all proton pump inhibitors.

They are commonly used as part of triple-therapy (i.e. Omeprazole & Amoxicillin & Clarithromycin) for [*Helicobacter pylori* eradication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicobacter_pylori_eradication_protocols). Successful eradication will cure most peptic ulcers.

The Australian [Barry Marshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Marshall) was awarded the [Nobel Prize in Physiology or Medicine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Marshall#Awards_and_honours) for 'discovery of the bacterium *Helicobacter pylori* and its role in gastritis and peptic ulcer disease'.

Granted, Amoxicillin is an older drug, but [Clarithromycin was released in the late 1980s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarithromycin#History).

Comment: That Helicobacter reference is great. What do proton pump inhibitors do? :o

Comment: @Brian: PPIs work as extremely effective 'antacids'. In fact, they stop H+ ions from being secreted into the stomach. Their mechanism of action is quite intriguing and I *believe* they are a product of rational drugs design (i.e. we have a target receptor and we design the drug to 'fit' it). This is opposed to 'brute force' drug design which is far and away the most common technique (e.g. combinatorial chemistry).

Comment: Cool. I had understand the discovery of cures to generally correlate with the utterance of "huh".

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt they prevent my stomach from producing so much acid it flows into my lungs... Yes, I've had that happen, it wasn't a nice experience at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another class of drug that I didn't think of before: Antidotes.

[Flumazenil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flumazenil) is a benzodiazepine antagonist. It was released in the 1980s. Benzodiazepines are commonly used sedatives. It's not uncommon to see patients in the A&E Department having administered an intentional benzodiazepine overdose. Due to their CNS depressant properties, [benzodiazepine overdose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzodiazepine_overdose#Signs_and_symptoms) is associated with respiratory depression, reduced psychomotor function, right through to coma and death (although death is uncommon when *only* benzodiazepines are involved).

Flumazenil will very effectively reverse the effects of benzodiazepines. It does have a fairly limited clinical use mind you.

The question is: Is intensional benzodiazepine overdose a 'human affliction'?

NB: Other places to look for new 'cures' would include anti-venoms, chelation therapy, radioactive isotopes, fentanyl analogues administered intrathecally (in order for this to be a pain 'cure' it would require that the patient die fairly soon after these were administered). There may be some others.